# Fetch and update a TwiML BIN through its TwiML BIN URL

Tags: twilio

I'm having a hard time trying to get my request to be signed in order to reach my TwiML BIN using the TwiML BIN URL (https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH.... )
even with the help from https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132187--Not-Authorized-error-when-trying-to-view-TwiML-Bin-URL

But I'm even doubting that this is what I need, as the goal is to be able to change the contents of my TwiML BIN.
I cannot find in the doc anything regarding this TwiML BIN URL and what you can use it for.
If it cannot be used to consult AND update my BIN, it's no use I keep trying to access it.

Some feedback would be greatly appreciated !!

thanks.

!!UPDATE!! - I can now connect but it looks like I only can do a GET and get the TwiML BIN 's contents, 
but I cannot modify (POST) anything.

Anyone knows whether this is by design (so I stop trying) ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

TwiML Bin URLs are not used for updating them. POST and GET will both respond the same to requests.

They should be updated through your Twilio console here: https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did find a solution using the dynamic templates in the bin and updating the voiceurl through REST calls... works fine.

Comment: Great to hear you got it to work the way you wanted!